# undefined reference to `_fcloseall'

Tags: c, windows

I am having trouble compiling my program.
The error message is: undefined reference to `_fcloseall', I think it could be a missing library file at the beginning. It might be also useful to know that I am programming on Windows 8.1 + Cygwin. Which library could be missing or do you see any other mistake?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void cleanup1();
void cleanup2();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE * file;
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("\ncommand bsp10085 <file>");
        exit(1);
    }
    assert(atexit(cleanup1) == 0);
    assert(atexit(cleanup2) == 0);
    if((datei = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL){
        printf("\nfile %s is being processed ..",argv[1]);
        fclose(datei);
    }
    else
        printf("\nfile '%s' is missing. ", argv[1]);
}

void cleanup1(){
    printf("\nCleanup the rest");
}

void cleanup2(){
    printf("\nClose all open files");
    fflush(NULL);
    _fcloseall();
}
```

Comment: I think it should probably be `fcloseall()`, not `_fcloseall()`. You may also need [#define _GNU_SOURCE](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fcloseal). Did you compile with `gcc -Wall ...`, and did you get any warnings ?

Comment: Is that an old version of Cygwin? This link mentions `fcloseall()` and `_fcloseall_r()` being added some time ago https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2002-07/msg01840.html

Comment: I just tried it with fcloseall, and it basically gave me the same error. Must be something with the version then I guess. Btw, already corrected the parts to "file" where there was "datei"

Comment: It's strange though, I am only using cygwin since 3 months, meaning it should be included in the actual version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compile your code (in ubuntu though) and i also got a warning: *warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fcloseall’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] fcloseall();*

I think that if you add

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

before

```
#include<stdio.h>
```

your program should work fine. This is your code after i changed some other warnings as well:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void cleanup1();
void cleanup2();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *datei;
    if(argc < 2){
        printf("\ncommand bsp10085 <file>");
        exit(1);
    }
    assert(atexit(cleanup1) == 0);
    assert(atexit(cleanup2) == 0);
    if((datei = fopen(argv[1], "r")) != NULL){
        printf("\nfile %s is being processed ..",argv[1]);
        fclose(datei);
    }
    else
        printf("\nfile '%s' is missing. ", argv[1]);
   return 0;
}

void cleanup1(){
    printf("\nCleanup the rest");
}

void cleanup2(){
    printf("\nClose all open files");
    fflush(NULL);
    fcloseall();
}
```

Comment: did not work unfortunately, still got the same error :(